# Unlimited Page Sizes

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using TableSorter 2.28.15 on a site with job listings to allow the visitor to sort the jobs based on a few of the columns.  However, the table is only displaying 15 rows, which I believe is a default.

Unfortunately, I can't tell where to change that?  The client doesn't want pager controls to let people navigate through the listings - they want them all to appear.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: So using the Pager plug-in, I was able to increase the number of rows that displayed.  I also set the fixedHeight to false to keep it from leaving a blank space when there weren't that many entries.  So I guess my new question is - do I just have to set this to a super high number, or is there an "unlimited" value that I can add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the pager `size` option to `"all"` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wty134u7/142/))

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue'
}).tablesorterPager({
    container: $(".pager"),
    size: 'all'
});
```

I'll need to update the documentation